# Google Sheets active column reference in regular expression

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanted to apply this only to selected column (only one column is selected) not a hardcoded one (A1:A)

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(regexextract(A1:A, "[0-9]+ ") * 0.25))
```

In my macro I just inserted a column after, the new column became active and it got the calculated result from the formula.

[This](https://filebin.net/75hbsl078ewf3o6q) is a video showing the result.

Comment: whats your issue?

Comment: I wanted to run this on a selected cell's column, not a predefined one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the `COLUMN()` function which gives me what I needed.

*Also there is the same for rows (`ROW()`).*

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the selected column into A1 notation like this. Note: I added some code to ensure only one column is selected.

```
function getA1NotationOfSelectedColumn() {
  const ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  if (ranges.length == 1) {
    const range = ranges[0];
    if (range.getNumColumns() == 1) {
      return range.getA1Notation();
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}
```